# Can we create Multiple databases in Same Persistent Volume in kubernetes ?

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, persistent-storage, kubectl

- I have Azure Machine (kubernetes) who have Agent of 2 core, 1 GB. My two services are running on this Machine each have its own Postgres (Deplyment, Service, Pv, PVC).
- I want to host my third service too on same machine.
- So when I tried to create Postgres Deployment (this too have its own service, PV, PVC) but Pod was stuck in `status=ContainerCreating` .
- After some digging I got to know that my `VM` only Supports `data-disks`.

So i thought why not use `PVC` of earlier deployment in current service like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: third-postgres
  labels:
    name: third-postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         name: third-postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: third-postgres
        image: postgres
        env:
          - name: PGDATA
            value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: third-user
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            value: <password>
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: third_service_db
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - name: third-postgresdata
      mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumes:
  - name: third-postgresdata
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: <second-postgres-data>
```

- Now this Deployment was successfully running but it doesn't create new database `third_service_db`
- May be because second `PVC` was already exists so it skips the Db create part ?
- So is their any way I can use same `PVC` for my all services and same `PVC` can have multiple databases. So that when I run `kubectl create -f <path-to-thirst-postgres.yaml>` it takes name Database configuration from env Variables and create DB in same `PVC`

Comment: PVC is used for requesting PV, so when you create your deployment(3rd service), it tries to provision a *NEW* PV for you and the status=ContainerCreating might be suggesting the provision was failed. Can you check your storage class?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one PVC per Deployment. Once a PVC has been *claimed*, it must be released before it can be used again.

In the case of AzureDisk, the auto-created volumes can only be mounted by a single node (*ReadWriteOnce* access mode) so there's one more constraint: each of your Deployments can have at most **1** replica.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create as much databas as you want on the same Persistent Volume. You have to change the `path` value to store different database. See the example below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: ...
  namespace: ...
  labels:
    type: ...
spec:
  storageClassName: ...
  capacity:
    storage: ...
  accessModes:
    - ...
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data/DIFFERENT_PATH_FOR_EACH_DATABASE"
```